# How to open deep link in flutter_inappwebview when opening init url and then the user is clicking icon app for opening deep link?

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I'm using `flutter_inappwebview` version `5.4.4+3` and having a problem with deep link on WebView.

```
InAppWebView(
   initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('https://www.google.com/contact/')),
)
```

When The `InitUrl` was opened in `InApp` WebView of the application, This page has an icon app (example: youtube, linkedIn, etc...) for the user's clicking and navigating to the respective app.

[image: page_init]

After the user clicks, My application can't load this page or navigate to the respective app.

```
Example Deep link: myapp://openapp?type=...
```

[image: unload_page]

How to fix this problem?

Comment: I would recommend using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

Answer (score 1):

I faced up the same problem.

I suppose your app already handles deeplinks and we can skip this step.

In this case, you have to add `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to your `InAppWebView` and open your link with the `url_launcher` plugin.

```dart
InAppWebView(
    shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
    
    final url = await controller.getUrl();
    final deeplink = navigationAction.request.url;

    if (deeplink != null && url != navigationAction.request.url) {
         launchUrl(deeplink, mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication);

         return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
    }

   return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
}
,
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, After googling for a while I found nothing.

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75768184/13898059) that [Eugene Kuzmenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4199283/eugene-kuzmenko) was provided is a good solution but when the user goes to another website and the URL is different It's going to be launched in an external browser, To solve this my code lauches the deep link If It doesn't have `https` or `http`.

Hope It helps:

```
  Future<NavigationActionPolicy?> checkDeepLink(
      InAppWebViewController inAppWebViewController,
      NavigationAction navigationAction) async {
    final url = await state.webviewController?.getUrl();
    final deepLink = navigationAction.request.url;

    if (deepLink != null &&
        url != navigationAction.request.url &&
        (deepLink.scheme != 'https' && deepLink.scheme != 'http')) {
      launchUrl(deepLink, mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication);
      return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
    }

    return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
  }
```